# Spring Security - Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

I am creating a RESTFul web api using spring security oauth2.0. I take a help of this http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html site.

While i try to run the program it shows an error saying

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#518c0ca0' while setting constructor argument with key [6]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpConfigurationBuilder$SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterBeanFactory#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore] for bean with name 'tokenStore' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml  
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
              authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
              xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                               after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
    and what roles have access to them -->
    <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
              entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
              access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
              xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>


    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
              xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
                                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>


    <!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password 
    combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users 
    credentials from DB -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="nishan" password="nishan" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>


    <!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now 
    but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
    <bean id="tokenStore"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
    and other things -->
    <bean id="tokenServices"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                               resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <!-- client -->
        <oauth:client client-id="restapp1"
                              authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
                              authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

        <oauth:client client-id="restapp2"
                              authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
                              secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <sec:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
        http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
</beans>
```

**Dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>    
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>  
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>  
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>  
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies>
```

Currently i am using spring mvc 4.3.12

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the class to "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"

That's the correct package according to the api docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/index.html

Comment: doesn't solve my problem. same error occurs

Comment: Is it for the same class? Because I see the TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler has also been changed to TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler

Comment: I solved the problem. it was the versioning problem of spring and spring security